How to Prevent PostgreSQL User with Connect on DB and Usage Granted on 1 Schema from Viewing Metadata on ALL Schemas
I've granted these permissions only, but somehow when I add a connection to DBeaver, PGAdmin 4 or DataGrip, the IDEs can see the tables and columns in ALL other schemas.
CREATE USER user_name WITH PASSWORD '***';
grant connect on database database_name to user_name;
grant usage on schema ext to user_name;
grant select on ext.table_1 to user_name;
grant select on ext.table_2 to user_name;

This user should be able to see the 2 tables that it has select grants on. It should not be able to see the tables and columns in other tables, or other schemas.
I have run the below SQl to ensure the user is not part of any group role that might have access to other schemas
SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE oid IN (
    SELECT roleid FROM pg_auth_members WHERE member = (SELECT oid FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'user_name')
);


seeing the tables and reading data from the tables, are two different things. GRANT only manages the access to the tables, not if you can see the table or not. You could REVOKE access to pg_class and other internal views, to obscure the data structure.
